# How to increase the size of pixels using variable in jspdf inside a loop. I tried the following code but its not showing what I want

Tags: javascript, jspdf

```
data.forEach(item=>{
    var i = 80;

    console.log(i)

    //here I want to increase the size of i (distance from the top)

    pdf.text(item.color , 15, i) ;
    pdf.text(item.label, 65, 100);
    i =+ 15
    console.log(i);
});
```

When loop completes its cycling, it prints all the data in the same place. Please look at the image. I want to print the lines separated by line break.

[image]

Comment: Is the overlapping text meant to be the chart's legend, or something else?

Comment: Yes, exactly it will be the chart's lagend, but because of this problem am unable to present it in the way I want to.....

Comment: And this overlapping is happening only in your PDF? Is everything alright, otherwise (when viewed in browser)?

Comment: everything is functional and I dont know what to do with this and am still waitng for a better response